# spark order by followed by partition by

Tags: apache-spark

I have below code snippets and I am little confused about the execution order of "orderBy" and "partitionBy".

`MY_DATA_FRAME.orderBy(ORDER_BY_FIELD).coalesce(NUM_OF_PARTITIONS).write.format("parquet").option("compression", "zip").partitionBy(PARTITION_BY_FIELD).option("path",LOCATION).save(FILE_NAME)`

May I know after `partitionBy` and then write to an output file, is this output file still satisfied order by `ORDER_BY_FIELD`?

Thank you.

Comment: Sharing my experiance but I am not a pro on spark. If you try this on a cluster order will be not guranteed if num_of_partions is more than 1 since its after order by. Saw a similar situation and order was fine on local spark but on cluster it was lost.

Answer (score 0):

**Looking at the `spark physical plan` it seems they don't perform any ordering operation while saving the partition file after `order by`, Hence i think, the ordering of the rows as specified in `order by` should be maintained**

```scala
 spark.sql(
      """
        |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_source_tab1 (col1 INT, p1 STRING, p2 STRING)
        |  USING PARQUET PARTITIONED BY (p1, p2)
      """.stripMargin).show(false)

    val table = spark.sql("select p2, col1 from values ('bob', 1), ('sam', 2), ('bob', 1) T(p2,col1)")
    table.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
    spark.sql(
      """
        |INSERT INTO data_source_tab1 PARTITION (p1 = 'part1', p2)
        |  SELECT p2, col1 FROM table order by col1
      """.stripMargin).explain(true)
```

Physical plan-

```scala
== Physical Plan ==
Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand file:/.../spark-warehouse/data_source_tab1, Map(p1 -> part1), false, [p1#14, p2#13], Parquet, Map(path -> file:/.../spark-warehouse/data_source_tab1), Append, CatalogTable(
Database: default
Table: data_source_tab1
Created Time: Wed Jun 10 11:25:12 IST 2020
Last Access: Thu Jan 01 05:29:59 IST 1970
Created By: Spark 2.4.5
Type: MANAGED
Provider: PARQUET
Location: file:/.../spark-warehouse/data_source_tab1
Partition Provider: Catalog
Partition Columns: [`p1`, `p2`]
Schema: root
-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
-- p1: string (nullable = true)
-- p2: string (nullable = true)
), org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CatalogFileIndex@bbb7b43b, [col1, p1, p2]
+- *(1) Project [cast(p2#1 as int) AS col1#12, part1 AS p1#14, cast(col1#2 as string) AS p2#13]
   +- *(1) Sort [col1#2 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
      +- Exchange rangepartitioning(col1#2 ASC NULLS FIRST, 2)
         +- LocalTableScan [p2#1, col1#2]
```